# Get specific values nested arrays elements in mongo collection by date

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection with objects like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "title": "myBook",
  "summary": "This is a book summary",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "number": 1
      "created_at": ISODate("2013-12-17T23:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      "number": 2
      "created_at": ISODate("2014-12-17T23:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
  "covers": [
    "http://url.com/cover1.jpg",
    "http://url.com/cover2.jpg",
  ],
  "urls": [
    "http://url.com/myBook",
    "http://url.com/myBook/option2"
  ],
  "genres": [
    "comedy",
    "romantic"
  ],
  "created_at": ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z"),
  "modify_at": ISODate("2014-02-01T15:41:48.149Z")
}
```

I only want to get books which 'crated_at' >= '2012-12-17T23:00:00Z' with only the chapters which 'created_at' > "2013-12-17T23:00:00Z". (As a filter)

My output json should be something like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "title": "myBook",
  "summary": "This is a book summary",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "number": 2
      "created_at": ISODate("2014-12-17T23:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
  "covers": [
    "http://url.com/cover1.jpg",
    "http://url.com/cover2.jpg",
  ],
  "urls": [
    "http://url.com/myBook",
    "http://url.com/myBook/option2"
  ],
  "genres": [
    "comedy",
    "romantic"
  ],
  "created_at": ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z"),
  "modify_at": ISODate("2014-02-01T15:41:48.149Z")
}
```

In the query output could be books without any chapters, others with a subset of all their chapters or books with all their chapters.

For to search books by 'created_at' I query by:

```
db.books.find({ created_at: {$gte: ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z")} })
```

but I don't know what I have to add for to filter the chapters in the output of this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do it with aggregation framework.

```
db.chapters.aggregate(
{ $match: { created_at: {$gte: ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z")} } },
{ $unwind: "$chapters" },
{ $match: { "chapters.created_at": {$gte: ISODate("2013-12-17T23:00:00Z")} } },
{ $group: 
    {
        _id: 
        {
            id: "$_id",
            title: "$title",
            summary: "$summary",
            covers: "$covers",
            urls: "$urls",
            genres: "$genres",
            created_at: "$created_at",
            modify_at: "$modify_at"
        },
        chapters: { $push: "$chapters" }
    }
},
{ $project:
    {
        _id: "$_id.id",
        title: "$_id.title",
        summary: "$_id.summary",
        chapters: "$chapters",
        covers: "$_id.covers",
        urls: "$_id.urls",
        genres: "$_id.genres",
        created_at: "$_id.created_at",
        modify_at: "$_id.modify_at"
    }
}
)
```

Comment: Wow ! Awesome query @Ivan.
I was not aware we can use same aggregations element multiple times in a query. Upvote for wonderful query